# Find the value of the constant $a$ which minimizes $E[(Y-aX)^2]$

Tags: probability, expectation

Let $X $ and $Y$ be random variable with $m_{x}$ and $m_{y}$ ,varainces $\sigma^{2}_{X}$ and $\sigma^{2}_{Y}$ ,and correlation coefficient $\rho_{X,Y}$

Find the value of the constant $a$ which minimizes $E[(Y-aX)^2]$

At first,i thought i can express the $E[(Y-aX)^2]$,that is ,

$E[(Y-aX)^2]$=$B$=$E[Y^2+a^2X^2-2YaX]$=$E[Y^2]+a^2E[X^2]-2aE[XY]$,then differentiate a to find the minimum $E[(Y-aX)^2]$.

$\frac{d}{da}B$=$2aE[X^2]-2E[XY]=0$,then when $a=\frac{E[X^2]}{E[XY]}$,we can minimizes $E[(Y-aX)^2]$ ?

Comment: It should be $\dots \color{red}{a^2}E[X^2]\dots$. And you can differentiate $2aE[XY]$, because $E[XY]$ is just a constant with respect to $a$.

Comment: but shouldn't i differentiate $X$ or $Y$? I think the $a$ is a constant

Comment: You want to differentiate with respect to $a$ to find the value of $a$ which minimizes the expression.

Comment: They call $a$ "constant" because it is nonrandom, but it is not constant because you can choose what it is. You want to find the best value of $a$, so you need to differentiate with respect to $a$.

Comment: i modify my formula,is my calculation correct?

Comment: @XM551 The expression looks correct to me, but I would further try to write it in terms of $m_x,m_y,\sigma^2_X,\sigma^2_Y$, and $\rho_{X,Y}$, as that's the "data" you're given for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the OP it says

$2aE[X^2] + 2E[XY] = 0\\a = \frac {E[X^2]}{E[XY]}$

This is inverted and should say

$2aE[X^2] + 2E[XY] = 0\\a = \frac {E[XY]}{E[X^2]}$

$\mu_X = E[X]\\
\sigma_X^2 = E[X^2] - E[X]^2\\
E[X^2] = \sigma^2_X + \mu^2_x\\ 
\text{cov}_{X,Y} = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]\\
E[XY] = \text {cov}_{X,Y} + \mu_X\mu_y$

$a = \frac {E[XY]}{E[X^2]} = \frac {(\text{cov}_{X,Y} + \mu_X\mu_Y)}{(\sigma^2_X + \mu^2_X)}$